# Directory not found error while the same is present in the list of directories

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I'm facing a very peculiar error:

```
# ls -l
drwxr-sr-x 8 kay users 4096 Aug 17 15:07 1. Crisis Core Workflow
drwxr-sr-x 6 kay users 4096 Aug 17 15:41 2. Contact Cards or Sheets    
drwxr-sr-x 3 kay users 4096 May 12 20:31 5. Distribution Lists

# cd 5.\ Distribution\ Lists
-bash: cd: 5. Distribution Lists: No such file or directory

# cd "5. Distribution Lists"
-bash: cd: 5. Distribution Lists: No such file or directory
```

There are no space issues here, I've checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tailing spaces you are unaware of

try

```
cd 5*
```

for starter, but trimming tail spaces would be welcome too

Comment: Or 'cd *5*' to cover any leading spaces too.

Answer (score 2):

Trailing space, perchance, or some other insane hidden character?  Try `cd 5<tab>`, and see what it fills out.

Answer (score 2):

cat -v only shows non-printing characters, which can be useful, but really, what you want is od -c

```
ls -d 5* | od -c
```

ls -d makes sure when you're listing a directory that you see the directory permissions as opposed to the files contained within the directory.

e.g.

```
$ mkdir "blah "
$ ls -d b* | od -c
0000000   b   l   a   h      \n
0000006
```

Comment: +1 for od, extremely useful tool

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of switches for ls that could help.

ls -w

ls -B

ls -b

-b may be the most useful, it will show non printable characters bu using their C escape codes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fsck'ing the partition?

Answer (score 0):

ls | cat -v 
should show you all the other "fun" characters that make up the filename :)